# Homeomorphism between Naturals and their inverses

Tags: general-topology

I am having troubles understanding homeomorphisms between, what I think are, dicrete sets:

$Z_0$ = $\mathbb{N}$,

$Z_1$ = $\{0\} \cup \{1/i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$Z_2$ = $Z_0 \cup Z_1$

Why are $Z_0$, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ not homeomorphic as subspaces of the real line (I thought that every discrete sets are homemorphic if only they are in a one-to-one correspondence)?

And why, in turn, are $Z_0 \times Z_1$ and $Z_0 \times Z_2$ homeomorphic?

I would be thankful for any directions

Comment: You should use mathjax. See See math.stackexchange.com/help/notation .

Answer (score 1):

That $Z_0 = \mathbb N$ and $Z_1 = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{i} \mid i \in \mathbb N\}$ cannot be homeomorphic you can see as follows:

A homeomorphism $f$ is a continuous function with a continuous inverse. In particular, $f$ [maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429902/image-of-a-convergent-sequence-under-a-continuous-function-converges).

In $Z_1$ (with the subspace topology induced by the metric topology on $\mathbb R$) the sequence $\frac{1}{i}$ converges to $0$. Hence if $f:Z_1 \to \mathbb N$ was a homeomorphism, $f(\frac{1}{i})$ would be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb N$ (again with respect to the topology induced by the metric topology on $\mathbb R$).

But this is not possible because in $\mathbb N$, with the given induced topology, all points are contained in the singleton open set $\{\frac{1}{i}\}$, so that none of these points can be the limit of a any sequence$^{1)}$.

1)For any $x$ that is the limit of a sequence all the open sets containing $x$ contain infinitely many points of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if $A,B$ are discrete subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with the same cardinality then they are homeomorphic as sub*spaces*, and it is also true that the three subsets in your question each have the same cardinality. However, **only $Z_0$ is discrete**: $0$ is a limit point of $Z_1$, and hence of $Z_2$ as well since $Z_1\subseteq Z_2$. **Remember that a set is discrete iff (by definition) it has no limit points**.

All three sets are **nowhere dense**, but nowhere-density is very far from discreteness and nowhere-dense sets of the same cardinality can be quite different from each other. I suspect this is the point of error: that you are conflating discreteness and nowhere-density.

*(As an aside, although not directly relevant to the current problem you might find it illuminating to consider how [a nowhere-dense set can have positive measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).)*

Comment: oh thank you, couls you may be also hint how is this possible that despite Z2 and Z1 being not homeomorphic their cartesian product with Z0 are?